# python threading issue with asynchronous http request

Tags: python, multithreading, asynchronous, urllib2

I'm building an asynchronous HTTP request class with urllib2.  The code looks like this:

```
import urllib2, threading, datetime

class ExportHandler(urllib2.HTTPHandler):
            def http_response(self, link, actualdate, nowdate ):
                link += "&export=csv"
                export = urllib2.urlopen( link )

for link, actualdate in commissionSummaryLinks:
            o = urllib2.build_opener(ExportHandler())
            t = threading.Thread(target=o.open, args=(link, actualdate, datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M%S")))
            t.start()

            print "I'm asynchronous!"
            t.join()

            print "ending threading"
```

Suffice it to say `commissionSummaryLinks` IS populated and `actualdate` is a `date time.datetime.strptime()` object.

Anyway, I'm receiving an error from all the issued threads that looks like this:

```
Exception in thread Thread-9:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 808, in __bootstrap_inner
   self.run()
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 761, in run
   self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 402, in open
   req = meth(req)
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1123, in do_request_
   'Content-length', '%d' % len(data))
TypeError: object of type 'datetime.date' has no len()
```

I'm running this on OS X (if it matters).  Can anyone tell me what the problem here is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you instantiate your thread, you need to provide the arguments to `o.open`, not arguments to the `http_response` method of `ExportHandler`.

In this case, `o.open` has the following method signature:

```
open(self, fullurl, data=None, timeout=<object object>) method of urllib2.OpenerDirector instance
```

My guess is that you should only need to set `args=(link,)`.

If you still need to use those other arguments, you'll probably want to modify the constructor of `ExportHandler` to take the other arguments you need, and then use them as appropriate in the `http_response` method. Take a look at [the Python Class tutorial](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#class-objects) for more information on defining a class constructor.

Comment: Ok, you are right, that seemed to work. However, what if I actually DO need the other arguments for more actions that take place within the ExportHandler class?  How would I pass those in?

Comment: @sadmicrowave, I expanded my original answer to address this.

Comment: awesome, but how do I get printing to work? The function is not doing the things it needs to do, yet I'm getting the output `I'm asynchronous!` and `ending threading` but nothing prints from within the `http_repsonse` method for me to troubleshoot and see how far the script gets...

Comment: @sadmicrowave, there aren't any `print` statements in the `http_response` method, so I wouldn't expect anything to be printed unless something was added there.

Comment: yes, I've added some lines in my code that differ from the OP.  Including a file write statement that should be writing files to a directory, but the files are not there after successfully completing the asynchronous requests, which leads me to believe that http_response() isn't being called at all...